# FB ID is returning as undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-control

I am using `var userID = (FB.getAuthResponse() || {}).userID;` to get ID of logged in user, FB .init is initialized properly.
The issue that I am encountering is If I put

```
var userID = (FB.getAuthResponse() || {}).userID;
```

inside `document.ready();` it is returned as undefined whereas if I put it in some javascript function and call that function on a button click, it works perfectly fine.

Anyone know what could be the issue?

I am also getting this when I try to access it directly on my website:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load {CALL o be MADE}. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin '{MY WEBSITE ADDRESS}' is therefore not allowed
>   access. (index)

PS: I don't get the above mentioned error in my facebook page tab, I only get this when I try to access directly my website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the asynchronous way to check if a user is logged in and to get his id:

> You should never use this method at page load time. Generally, it is
>   safer to use FB.getLoginStatus if you are unsure.

Check out the Facebook docs for code and information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus

**Of course you should call this right after FB.init.**

Comment: asynchronous way? yo mean via some ajax call to server?

Comment: getLoginStatus is asynchronous, just check out the docs. it offers a callback function that is called asynchronously.

Comment: thank you, but just wondering, why on click that works and on page load it doesn't

Comment: it depends when you use it. it must be used after fb.init.

Comment: "i am sure" or "i actually do"? :) - well, getLoginStatus is definitely much better ans recommended by facebook, but feel free to post your code in your question so i can take a look.